# Salesforce - success handler for $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce

I have a form that I have been submitting to Salesforce with standard form submit action. By default, you can tell Salesforce to redirect you to a given URL after the POST has completed.

I no longer wish to be redirected since I have other activities on the form page. No problem, my page is already using jQuery so I can use the handy $.ajax utility like this:

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '#formsubmit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $('#subForm').serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8",
      data: formData,
      success: function() {
        console.log('success!'); // or not!
      },
      error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    console.log(xhr.status); // 0
                    console.log(thrownError); // empty
                }
    });
});
```

In my misguided brain, I imagined that Salesforce would return my good ol' redirect, which would count as a "success" that I can just discard/ignore. Misguided indeed!

- I can see a 200 OK result (which usually means "success") but the success callback isn't tripped.
- The lead *is* added to the Salesforce database
- Inspecting the content of what's returned shows zero; there is no content in the response.
- The error callback *IS* being tripped (despite the 200 OK) but maybe due to  intentionally not redirecting it is seen as a "resource not available"? (therefore my status code is 0, and there is no content in the thrownError?).

Any advice on identifying this as a successful POST so that I can trigger additional actions in a callback? I don't want to TOTALLY ignore the response, or I could end up in a scenario in which I'm acting on a failed POST as if it was successful. I need to capture the success somehow.

It occurred to me that it could be a cross-site scripting issue as well, but since the application doesn't exchange data in JSONP, I'm not sure how to get around that (and I'm not sure how to identify it in the first place).

Comment: A little googling yields this: http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZojFAAS  Based on that, more than likely salesforce doesn't currently support cross-origin sharing other than for flash. I suggest using a server-side page that makes the request for you until the salesforce api returns the correct CORS headers.

Comment: Thanks for that research, Kevin. I think you and C.Hill are on to something.

Comment: Once the correct headers are being returned you can use the post you have above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things here:

1) The redirect response being sent by salesforce's API is most likely being interpreted as an error code.

2) The response code of the subsequent page (after the redirect) is 200 OK, from the sound of it.

3) It is not possible to do a POST request using JSONP. This is a limitation of JSONP; which is not actually an AJAX request, but an HTTP GET request wrapped inside of a dynamically generated *script* tag. Also, JSONP only works if the request yields an HTTP response of 200 OK.

I would recommend using your own server-side intermediary to handle your AJAX POST request. This will act as a proxy between your front-end app and salesforce's API. This will also allow you to better control the response being sent to your app.

Comment: Thanks, C.Hill. It never occurred to me to use the server side as an itermediary... that might be the ticket.

Comment: I have to admit, I haven't implemented this as of yet; I am going to try to reverse order of events and see if I can do the other activity first (though I think I'll run into the same cross-site problems; the main additional activity is a Constant Contact subscription; their API probably also does not return CORS headers); be that as it may, it's clear that this is a great approach so I'm going to go ahead and accept the answer now so that I don't forget.

Answer (score 0):

```
var formData = $('#subForm').serialize();
   var response = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8",
      data: formData,
      success: function() {
        console.log('success!'); // or not!
      },
      error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    console.log(xhr.status); // 0
                    console.log(thrownError); // empty
                }
    }).responseText;
```

where var response will contain the return value from your ajax call

Comment: It's an empty string, which I was also able to confirm just by looking in the console.